# The property of Lebesgue inner measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

For ***bounded*** set $E \subset \mathbb{R^n},$ difine the Lebesgue inner measure $m_*$ as below.

$m_*(E):=m^*(Q)-m^*(Q\cap E^c)
\big(=v(Q)-m^*(Q\cap E^c)\big)$

where $Q$ is a closed hypercube in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $E\subset Q$,  $m^*$ is Lebesgue outer measure and $v(Q)$ stands for the volume of $Q$.

Then, prove that $m_*(E)$ doesn't depend on the choice of $Q$, i.e., if closed hypercubes $Q_1, Q_2$ satisfy $E\subset Q_1$ and $E\subset Q_2$, then $v(Q_1)-m^*(Q_1\cap E^c)=v(Q_2)-m^*(Q_2\cap E^c).$

I tried to prove this using the definition of $m^*$ but it didn't seem to work.

I'd like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: Prove that if c(E) is the set of  closed bounded subsets of $E$ then $m_*(E)=\sup \{m^*(F): F\in c(E)\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Let $S:=\{m^*(F) \ | \ F \text{ is closed }, F\subset E \}.$ The statement is $m_*(E)=\sup S$.  I could prove that $m_*(E)$ is an upper bound of $S$, but I couldn't prove that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists$ closed set $F$ such that $F\subset E$ and $m_*(E)-\epsilon < m^*(F)$. How can I prove this?

Comment: Let $O$ be an open set with $O\supset Q\cap E^c$ and $m^*(O)<m^*(Q\cap E^c)+\epsilon.$ Then $F=Q\cap O^c$  is a closed subset of $E.$ Let $O'$ be an open set with $O'\supset F$ and $m^*(O')< m^*(F)+\epsilon.$ Then $m^*(Q)\le m^*(O)+m^*(O')<m^*(Q\cap E^c)+m^*(F)+2\epsilon.$ Therefore $ m^*(F)>m^*(Q)-m^*(Q\cap E^c)-2\epsilon=m_*(E)-2\epsilon.$